# Div is not showing up in page when created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hello my new div is not appearing in my html site when the function is ran. It creates the div but its not visible. Im new to js and any help will be appreciated. Excuse my bad programming skills.

```
function newProject(projectName, projectLang, projectDifficulty) {
    let newProjectBox = document.createElement('div'); 
    newProjectBox.className = 'projectbox';
    newProjectBox.innerHTML = 
    `<img src="/projectImages/snake-icon.png" alt="Project">
    <h3 id="projectName">${projectName}</h3>
    <h3 id="projectLang">Project Language: ${projectLang}</h3>
    <h3 id="projectDifficuly">Difficulty: ${projectDifficulty}</h3>`;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end you have to append this in the document to be useful

```
document.body.appendChild("div");
```

in the line

```
let newProjectBox = document.createElement('div');
```

you first have to call this to create a div before converting it into a variable.
This has to go like.

```
document.createElement("div");
let newProjectBox = document.createElement("div");
```

then you can continue your normal code.
and finally call your function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your new div inside a parent div.

for example:

```
<div id="main"></div>

function newProject(projectName, projectLang, projectDifficulty) {
            let newProjectBox = document.createElement('div'); 
            newProjectBox.className = 'projectbox';
            newProjectBox.innerHTML = 
            `<img src="/projectImages/snake-icon.png" alt="Project">
            <h3 id="projectName">${projectName}</h3>
            <h3 id="projectLang">Project Language: ${projectLang}</h3>
            <h3 id="projectDifficuly">Difficulty: ${projectDifficulty}</h3>`;

            /* here */
            document.getElementById('main').appendChild(newProjectBox);
        };
```

result:

```
<div id="main">
 <div class="projectbox">
   <img src="/projectImages/snake-icon.png" alt="Project">
   <h3 id="projectName">NAME</h3>
   <h3 id="projectLang">Project Language: LANG</h3>
   <h3 id="projectDifficuly">Difficulty: DIFFICULTY</h3>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only create `div` element and you have to append it to any element within the body. For example you can try to append it to the root body:

```
document.body.append(newProjectBox)
```

Full example:

```js
function newProject(projectName, projectLang, projectDifficulty) {
    let newProjectBox = document.createElement('div'); 
    newProjectBox.className = 'projectbox';
    newProjectBox.innerHTML = 
    `<img src="/projectImages/snake-icon.png" alt="Project">
    <h3 id="projectName">${projectName}</h3>
    <h3 id="projectLang">Project Language: ${projectLang}</h3>
    <h3 id="projectDifficuly">Difficulty: ${projectDifficulty}</h3>`;
    document.body.append(newProjectBox)
};
```

If you have a container id like `root` or something, you need to adjust your code like:

```js
var target = document.getElementById("root")
target.append(newProjectBox)
```